# Externalize Spring Boot application properties in PCF

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, pcf

Hi I'm on working spring boot and I need to host the application in PCF. so I need to host the application according to environment. so I need to externalize the application properties and deploy it in PCF. there options like profiling based on environment another option is referring the application in some storage and referring it at runtime. so whether these options are achievable in PCF, if so can you please help me with sample example.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore spring profiles and switch on to any required environment related application properties by injecting the property spring.profiles.active. Please refer the [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) which could explain in more details.

You can simply set an environment variable to enable it on PCF as below (example for dev env):

```
cf set-env APP_NAME JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

The `<springProperty>` tag lets you expose properties from the Spring Environment for use within Logback. Please refer the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.logback-extensions)

Comment: Can i also use spring-logback.xml for externalising. so that i can refer the application properties from my external file source..

Comment: Yeah, I think logback-spring.xml can also be used. Answer updated above..